# Watch puma output on local network from another device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

So I'm trying to teach my girlfriend rails and I was wondering if there's a way I can follow her server output/activity from another computer on the same network? Basically the same way I would see my own logs after booting up the server using `rails s`.

She's running puma and currently setup at `-b ip_address -p 3000`

Thanks!

Comment: No I don't think that is possible without setting up any file sharing mechanism. Of course it is possible to send requests to the server on the other computer, by just sending requests to `<localip>:3000` where `localip` is the address of the other computer.

Comment: If you can SSH into the computer its as easy as running `tail -f /logs/development.log`. For being able to connect to their development server I would really recommend a tunnel like NGrok which removes a lot of the setup headaches as not all OS:es will forward requests from the ip to localhost.

Comment: We're both on Mac OS Catalina; do you have any idea where I can look to do what you're suggesting, Max?